# How to initialize a class stored in a variable in python

Tags: python, class

I am wondering if it is possible to initialize a class stored in a variable. For example:

```
class cl():
    def __init(self, a):
        self.a = a

        return
    def print(self):

        print(self.a)
        return a

In[27]: c = cl
In[28]: c
Out[28]: __main__.cl
```

and now I want to initialize `cl` with value of `a=3`

Comment: `c = cl` and now we can `a = c(3)`

Comment: `__init` needs to be written `__init__`. Are you sure this is 100% identical to your code?

Comment: why are you even doing `c=cl`?

Comment: This all points to you needing to go through a Python tutorial. Maybe a different one than the one you've been reading this far.

Comment: yet there was an error `__init__` was correct

Comment: ok maybe the question was a bit easy but I do not see why this should be downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class cl():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def print_a(self):
        print(self.a)

c = cl
c(3)
c.print_a()
>>> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is totally possible. When you do `c = c1` it creates `c` as an exact alias of `c1`.

You then do

```
obj_from_c1 = c1()
obj_from_c c()
```